# I have created a GET API and want to assign the fetched values to the textboxes in ASP.NET application. How can I do that?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, ado.net

I have created a `GET` API method and want to assign the fetched values to the textboxes in an ASP.NET application. I am not able to assign the values in the asp textbox. Please help me here.I am new to Web API and I want to assign the values fetched from API to each textbox but I am unable to understand it how to add it.

This is the code for API - model class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace CollegeUniverseAPI.Models.Students
{
    public class StudentDetails
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Gender {  get; set; }
        public string Email {  get; set; }
        public string Father { get; set; }
        public string Mother {  get; set; }
        public string Batch {  get; set; }
        public string Semester { get; set; }
        public string Contact {  get; set; }
        public int Roll {  get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using CollegeUniverseAPI.Models.Students;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace CollegeUniverseAPI.Controllers
{
    public class StudentDetailsController : ApiController
    {
        string connect = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CollegeAPI"].ConnectionString;

        StudentDetails std = new StudentDetails();

        public StudentDetails Get(string Username)
        {
            using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connect)) 
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[spStudentDetails]", con);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);

                con.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                reader.Read();
                std.ID = (int)reader["ID"];
                std.Name = (string)reader["Name"];
                std.Gender = (string)reader["Gender"];
                std.Email = (string)reader["Email"];
                std.Father = (string)reader["Fathers_Name"];
                std.Mother = (string)reader["Mothers_Name"];
                std.Batch = (string)reader["Batch"];
                std.Semester=(string)reader["Semester"];
                std.Contact = (string)reader["Contact"];
                std.Roll = (int)reader["Roll_No"];
                std.Department=(string)reader["Department"];
                return std;
            }
        }

        public string Put(int ID, StudentDetails std) 
        {
            string msg = "";

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connect))
            {
                StudentDetails student = new StudentDetails();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spStudentDetailsUpdate", con);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",std.Name);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender",std.Gender);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email",std.Email);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Father",std.Father);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mother",std.Mother);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sem",std.Semester);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contact",std.Contact);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Roll",std.Roll);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department",std.Department);

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                msg = "Details Updated for "+ID;
                return msg;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my HTML markup:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MainMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="StudentDetails.aspx.cs" Inherits="College_Database.StudentDetails" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 180px;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <header class="ContentHead">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg" style="background-color: #e3f2fd; width:100%">
  <div class="container-fluid">
      <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" CssClass="backbutton" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Image/home.jpg" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" />
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
               <li class="nav-item" style="margin-left:1vw">
           <asp:LinkButton CssClass="nav-link active hover text-decoration-none" ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click">Academics</asp:LinkButton>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <asp:LinkButton CssClass="nav-link active hover text-decoration-none" ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" OnClick="LinkButton2_Click">Personal Details</asp:LinkButton>
       </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="welcome">
          <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" style="margin-right:2vw;"></asp:Label>
      </div>
  </div>
</nav>
</header>
<main class="StudentBody">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="studentbutton">
                <b>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" style="margin-left:1vw;"></asp:Label>
</b>
        <asp:Button class="btn btn-danger" ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Logout" OnClick="Button1_Click" data-bs-toggle="button" style="margin-left:76vw;margin-top:auto;"/>
                <br />
                <br />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
            <div>
                <table style="width:100%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style1">Student ID</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="ID" runat="server" Width="300px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style1">Name</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server" Width="300px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style1">Gender</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Gender" runat="server" Width="300px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style1">Email</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" Width="300px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style1">Father's Name</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Father" runat="server" Width="300px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style1">Mother's Name</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Mother" runat="server" Width="300px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style1">Batch</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Batch" runat="server" Width="300px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style1">Semester</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Semester" runat="server" Width="300px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style1">Contact</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Contact" runat="server" Width="300px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style1">Roll No.</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Roll" runat="server" Width="300px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="auto-style1">Department</td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="Department" runat="server" Width="300px" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
                </div>
            <br />
            <div class="container">
                <asp:Button class="btn btn-warning" ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Update Details" data-bs-toggle="button"  OnClick="Button2_Click"/>
            </div>
    </main>
</asp:Content>
```

And this is my C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace College_Database
{
    public partial class StudentDetails : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                if (Session["StudentUsername"] == null)
                {
                    var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StudentLogin"];
                    Response.Redirect(url);
                }

                string connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CollegeDB"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connection))
                {
                    //SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("spStudentName", con);
                    //command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    //command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Session["Username"]);
                    con.Open();
                    //string SessionName = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                    Label1.Text = "Welcome " + Session["Name"] + "!";
                    Label2.Text = Session["Session"].ToString();
                    //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spStudentDetails", con);
                    //cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Session["StudentUsername"]);
                    //SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    //reader.Read();
                    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:63273/api/StudentDetails");
                    var response = client.GetAsync("StudentDetails?Username=" + Session["StudentUsername"]);
                    response.Wait();
                    var result = response.Result;
                    
                    ID.Text = result["ID"];
                    Name.Text = 
                    Gender.Text = 
                    Email.Text = 
                    Father.Text = 
                    Mother.Text = 
                    Batch.Text = 
                    Semester.Text = 
                    Contact.Text = 
                    Roll.Text = 
                    Department.Text = 
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the JSON response from the Web API and then assign the values to your textboxes

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["StudentUsername"] == null)
    {
        var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StudentLogin"];
        Response.Redirect(url);
    }

    string apiUrl = "http://localhost:63273/api/StudentDetails?Username=" + Session["StudentUsername"];

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(apiUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(apiUrl).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var studentDetails = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<StudentDetails>().Result;

            // Now you can assign the values to your textboxes
            ID.Text = studentDetails.ID.ToString();
            Name.Text = studentDetails.Name;
            Gender.Text = studentDetails.Gender;
            Email.Text = studentDetails.Email;
            Father.Text = studentDetails.Father;
            Mother.Text = studentDetails.Mother;
            Batch.Text = studentDetails.Batch;
            Semester.Text = studentDetails.Semester;
            Contact.Text = studentDetails.Contact;
            Roll.Text = studentDetails.Roll.ToString();
            Department.Text = studentDetails.Department;
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle the case where the API call is not successful
            // You can display an error message or take appropriate action.
        }
    }
}
```